# The zero set of a real function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all  continuous real functions $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)/x^k=0$$ for $k=1,2,...$ . It follows, for each $f\in S$, that $f(0)=0$. Is it true that $0$ is the only common root of the elements of $S$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $f(x)=0$ works, and it has other roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Claim: the only common root of *all* the elements of $S$ is $x=0$.

For proving it, it is sufficient to find a function $f\in S
 $ such that the only root of $f$ is at $x=0$. So let us consider $$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x}, & x\in\left(0,1\right]\\
0, & x=0.
\end{cases}
 $$ We have that $f$ is continuous on $\left[0,1\right]
 $, $f(0)=0$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{k}}=0,\,\forall k\geq1
 $$ so $f\in S
 $ and the only root of $f$ is at $x=0$.

Comment: @karparvar Oh sorry, I didn't read "all" :) thank you for pointing out it. In this case the answer is yes. I will write the answer.